# Vue Using Computed Property Values in Data Properties?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, computed-properties

I am trying take an array from a computed property and add it to a data property in my Vue app. The reason I am doing this is a method I am calling I need the length of the array in that computed property. So what I have is:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
      return {
        //assigning the jobs JSON data to this variable
        jobs: jsonData,
        jobsFiltered: //this is where the computed property variable should go.

        locations: ['Chicago', 'Philly', 'Baltimore'],

        //Used to filter based on selected filter options
        selectedLocation: '',

        page: 1,
        perPage: 10,
        pages: [],
      }
    },

methods: {
            setPages () {
              this.pages = [];
              let numberOfPages = Math.ceil(this.jobs.length / this.perPage);
              for (let i = 1; i <= numberOfPages; i++) {
                this.pages.push(i);
              }
            },

            paginate (jobs) {
              let page = this.page;
              let perPage = this.perPage;
              let from = (page * perPage) - perPage;
              let to = (page * perPage);
              return  jobs.slice(from, to);
            },
        },

computed: {

  filteredJobs: function(){
    var filteredList = this.jobs.filter(el=> {
      return el.customText12.toUpperCase().match(this.selectedLocation.toUpperCase())
    });

    return this.paginate(filteredList);
  }

}


})
```

So what I need to happen is I need to set the data variable of jobsFiltered to the variable in computed properties of filteredList. The reason I need this is to add the length of the array of filteredList to the variable of numberOfPages in the setPages method:

```
let numberOfPages = Math.ceil(this.jobs.length / this.perPage);
```

So where it says this.jobs.length I actually need to get the length of the filteredList array instead and I am unsure how to do this when the array I am trying to get the length of is a computed property.

EDIT: Adding some more clarity, I am running the paginate method on the filteredList variable in the filteredJobs function in computed properties. So what that is doing is running the slice method on that filteredList variable and only giving me 10 array items at a time. So when I do `this.filteredJobs.length` it sees the length of that is 10 and not getting the full length. When I actually need the length of the array before the slice method is ran on it.

Comment: You can just do `this.filteredJobs.length`, use it the same as a data property. No need to re declare it.

Comment: @Psidom See I tried that, but the issue with that is I am running the paginate method on the filteredList variable in the filteredJobs function in computed properties. So what that is doing is running the slice method on that filteredList variable and only giving me 10 array items at a time. So when I do `this.filteredJobs.length` it sees the length of that is 10 and not getting the full length. When I actually need the length of the array before the slice method is ran on it.

Comment: Then my suggestion is to separate filteredList and filteredJobs into two computed properties, and then do `this.filteredList.length`

Comment: @Psidom Okay awesome making it to separate computed properties instead of trying to do it all in one worked! Thanks!